# Center a block of two Views in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want a block of two labels to be horizontally centered in the screen, currently I have the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Test 2"
        android:textColor="#00ff00" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is ok when the text are short (see image below):

[image]

But when the red text is long (or the screen is narrow) the green text is missing:

[image]

Since green text is a single word I want it to have priority, beeing always visible ellipsing the red 
if needed (and keeping the block centered)

This is how it should look like:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Note: I need to use two TextView since they must be animated

Comment: android:layout_centerHorizontal=true

Comment: @nobalG: it´s a linearLayout, layout_centerHorizontal=true is a relativeLayout attribute.

Comment: Change the width of the red TextView to `0dp` and set its `layout_weight` to 1.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs if the OP changes the layout then will it solve the problem for him?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the layout, it has something to do with the weights. Mike M´s answer is wright. @Mike M. add this as an answer... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here try this:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#00ff00" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use layout_weight atribute.

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum"
    android:textColor="#ff0000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Test 2"
    android:textColor="#00ff00" /></LinearLayout>
```

Hope its help.

Answer (score 1):

I get the result that you expect using weight:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Lorem ipsumsvasvdfbfgnbgndnnghnghnghngngnbfgbsdfbsdfdsfvsdfvfv"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Test 2"
        android:textColor="#00ff00" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is the weight of the second textView?

Comment: You don't need to put weight to the second textView .Test the code you will see that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Give Max Width attribute to TextView2 dynamically, it should be  :
Get Screen Dimensions [Width] first and then TextView1 width.

```
int maxWidth  = ScreenWidthSize - WidthOfTextView1;
textView2.setMaxWidth(maxWidth);
```

or if u want custom width for each in dp then in XML:

```
 android:maxWidth="200dp"
```

Hard coded for each.

Answer (score -1):

i think u need not use two text views take one text view and use SpannableStringBuilder.

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        SpannableString redSpannable = new SpannableString("here first string");
        redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")), 0, "here first string".length(), 0);
        builder.append(redSpannable);
        builder.append(" ");

        String white =  upperCase.toUpperCase();
        SpannableString whiteSpannable = new SpannableString("here second string");
        whiteSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#00ff00")), 0, "here second string".length(), 0);
        builder.append(whiteSpannable);
TextView02.setText(builder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```